# Would I use a reverse thread lag screw swage stud for tensioning cable?

Tags: screws, fence, wire

I was watching several videos showing an installation of wire rope for a fence, and the lag screw swage stud on one end would be driven **clockwise** while the other goes in **counterclockwise**. That way it can be tightened correctly, which makes sense.

In the video, both terminal ends are the same, the only exception being that one has regular threading and the other one has reverse threading.

My question: how can I drive a lag screw swage stud counterclockwise? Would I need to buy one with this type of threading?

The reason for the question is that I want to buy [something like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B078RZ9J8R), but it doesn't include anything about reverse threading or going in counterclockwise. None of the items in this page mention anything like this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'd purchase swage hardware in both "hands". Swages in left-hand thread (LHT) are readily available, as seen [here](http://www.miamistainless.com.au/general-hardware/rigging-screw-bottlescrew/lag-screw-swage), for example.

The alternative would be to use swiveling swage fittings, which will allow you to tension the cables without regard for direction.

Comment: Thanks. That's the video I saw. The issue is that they're in Australia and I'm in the US.

Comment: How would the swiveling swage fitting work? Would it work with a 4"x4" wood post?

Comment: You said your question has nothing to do with availability. Whether a swage has a swivel is unrelated to the type of post. It simply allows the cable to spin at one or both ends.

Comment: But where can I buy something [like this](https://www.amazon.com/Muzata-10PCS-Railing-Stainless-Marine/dp/B078RZ9J8R/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1539111000&sr=8-1&keywords=lag+screw+swage+stud+for+1%2F8+cable+railing+stainless+steel), but with regular threading and reverse-threading?

Comment: You're asking us to shop for you, which (as you well know) is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a turnbuckle is used for tightening wire rope the turnbuckle has 1 threaded eye that is normal right handed threads and one eye that has a left handed thread so as you turn the turn buckle 1 direction it tightens and the opposite direction loosens the tension.

Added 2 ways to tighten swage lags, #1 use a drill in reverse (it will probably need to have a low gear to have the torque my dewalt 3 speed with variable trigger will drive 1/2" eye lags so I know it can be done). #2 use a wrench on the flats.

Comment: Yes, but then I saw this option today and considered it since it's less expensivee than the turnbuckles.

Comment: If they are cheaper but you can't find them are they really cheaper?

Comment: They're available at amazon. My question has nothing to do with availability.

Comment: It is a left hand thread you spin them in the same way you would a normal swage lag but instead of turning clockwise you turn counter clockwise . I haven't used ccw lags but might be concerned it may loosen or tighten the twist on the wire rope. I know of 2 ways to install them #1 is to use a drill in reverse (if it has low gears to provide the torque) #2 is use a wrench on the flats. If this doesn't answer your question you may want to clarify it.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that I can't find any in the US that have reverse/left-hand threading.

Comment: @isherwood provided a link I just looked and found luxline not sure exactly where they are but they specify mountian time zone for there phone number. Originally i was looking at non swivel types as I have not used the swaged types it looks like you will need a swaging tool to create the proper or nice look.